# how to print data from db in php?

Tags: php, sql

i have this code and i want to print the data from company data. how will i deal with it? the page only shows while blank page. anyone? please help

```
<?php
    include 'dbconnection.php';
    session_start();

            $id = $_SESSION['id'];
            $sql="Select * from company where CompanyID = :id"; //query
            $res=$db->prepare($sql);
            $res->execute(array('id'=> $id));   

            while($row = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
                $name = $row['Name'];
                print_r($name);
                echo "</br>";
                echo $row['Address'];
                echo "</br>";
                echo $row['Telephone1'];
                echo "</br>";
                echo $row['Telephone2'];
                echo "</br>";
                echo $row['BusinessWebsite'];
                echo "</br>";
                echo $row['BusinessEmail'];
                echo "</br>";
                echo $row['BusinessPermit'];
                echo "</br>";
                echo $row['BusinessPermitValidTill'];
                echo "</br>";
                echo $row['DTIPermit'];
                echo "</br>";
                echo $row['DTIPermitValidTill'];
                echo "</br>";
                echo $row['BankName'];
                echo "</br>";
                echo $row['BankAccountNumber'];
                echo "</br>";
            }
    ?>
```

the code below is the dbconnection.php which i include in the code above

```
    class Database extends pdo {

        private $dbtype; 
        private $host;     
        private $user;
        private $pass; 
        private $database; 

        public function __construct(){ 
            $this->dbtype = 'mysql'; 
            $this->host = 'localhost'; 
            $this->user = 'root'; 
            $this->pass = 'root'; 
            $this->database = 'sad'; 
            $dns = $this->dbtype.':dbname='.$this->database.";host=".$this->host; 
            parent::__construct( $dns, $this->user, $this->pass ); 
        }     
    }

    $database = new Database();
    $db =& $database;

    ?>
```

Comment: Define "print", do you mean on paper or to display it on a a webpage?

Comment: Add `ini_set("display_errors",1);` on top of your file to check error on page if any.

Comment: What's inside **dbconnection.php**, perhaps you don't have pdo errors on

Comment: @Dai what i mean with print was display to web

Comment: @Johnny000<?php

class Database extends pdo {

    private $dbtype; 
    private $host;     
    private $user;
    private $pass; 
    private $database; 

    public function __construct(){ 
        $this->dbtype = 'mysql'; 
        $this->host = 'localhost'; 
        $this->user = 'root'; 
        $this->pass = 'root'; 
        $this->database = 'sad'; 
        $dns = $this->dbtype.':dbname='.$this->database.";host=".$this->host; 
        parent::__construct( $dns, $this->user, $this->pass ); 
    }     
}

$database = new Database();
$db =& $database;

?>

Comment: Put it in the questions above the other code, formatted as code so everybody can see it.

Comment: I think you are missing $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice manual [right here](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

From which you can learn what you don't need to set fetch mode explicitly with every fetch.
...and even what with PDO you don't need no arrays at all to echo a number:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT number FROM table WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($id));
echo "Hello User, your number is".$stmt->fetchColumn();
```

**OR**

```
<?php
   $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');
   $stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table");
   $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   var_dump($results);
?>
```

This is a nice tutorial: [PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)